# Executing wait-for-it.sh in python Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, exec, docker-compose, wait

I have a Python docker container that needs to wait until another container (postgres server) finishes setup.  I tried the standard wait-for-it.sh but several commands weren't included. I tried a basic sleep (again in an sh file) but now it's reporting `exec: 300: not found` when trying to finally execute the command I'm waiting on.

How do I get around this (preferably without changing the image, or having to extend an image.)

I know I could also just run a Python script, but ideally I'd like to use wait-for-it.sh to wait for the server to turn up rather than just sleep.

Dockerfile (for stuffer):

```
 FROM python:2.7.13

 ADD ./stuff/bin /usr/local/bin/
 ADD ./stuff /usr/local/stuff
 WORKDIR /usr/local/bin

 COPY requirements.txt /opt/updater/requirements.txt
 COPY internal_requirements.txt /opt/stuff/internal_requirements.txt

 RUN pip install -r /opt/stuff/requirements.txt
 RUN pip install -r /opt/stuff/other_requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: '3'
 services:
   local_db:
     build: ./local_db
     ports:
     - "localhost:5432:5432"

   stuffer:
     build: ./
     depends_on:
     - local_db
     command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "-t", "300", "localhost:5432", "--", "python", "./stuffing.py", "--file", "./afile"]
```

Script I want to use (but can't because no psql or exec):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # wait-for-postgres.sh

 set -e

 host="$1"
 shift
 cmd="$@"

 until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
   sleep 1
 done

 >&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
 exec $cmd
```

Comment: Could you show me Dockerfile and entrypoint please?

Comment: What's the best way to install bash commands as needed.  I know I could theoretically install postgres in the python image to have psql, but exec isn't something I should be installing.

Comment: try to change line `command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "-t", "300", "localhost:5432", "--", "python", "./stuffing.py", "--file", "./afile"]` to `command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "localhost:5432",  "-t", "300", "--", "python", "./stuffing.py", "--file", "./afile"]`
wait for it expects that  first argument will be a hostname:port

Comment: I think I see the issue. Like you're saying. "300" isn't a command for exec. Just looking at it I thought that was a line number somewhere.  Apologies for the stupid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sergey's comment. I had wrong argument order. This issue had nothing to do with docker and everything to do with my inability to read.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example so you can see it working:

https://github.com/nitzap/wait-for-postgres

On the other hand also you can have errors inside the execution of the script to validate that the service is working. You should not refer as localhost .... because that is within the contexts of containers, if you want to point to another container has to be through the name of the service.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on that?  My goal is for the postgres container to be bound to localhost on the host machine and then the second container connects to it.  (The purpose of these containers is to have a standard local dev db setup).

Comment: If you can see the project, the application container expects the postgres container is ready. Now if you want to use the base separately, the port is also published as if it were local.